# Exception when using DllImport on unmanaged DLL containing Thread-Local-Storage (TLS) callback

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a .NET application that loads an unmanaged DLL (C++) containing several entry points.
The setup works fine and I can use information returned (i.e. strings) by the entry points in .NET.
But as soon as the linker includes logic that depends on threads (e.g. _beginthread) a .tls section is added to DLL, which can be
seen by running dumpbin /exports, then the program throws exceptions: Access violations and EntryPointNotFound exceptions.

As an example I have created two simple projects that demonstrates my case:

- TestApi: C++ project that outputs a DLL
- ConsoleApplication1: C#.NET project that loads TestApi.dll and invokes an exported DLL function

The above project doesn't include calls to _beginthread, but instead a Thread-Local-Storage (TLS) callback was added manually, which causes the run-time errors.
The example projects can be downloaded here: http://www.tempfiles.net/download/201404/343692/TestApi.html

The C# code of ConsoleApplication1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("TestApi.dll", EntryPoint = "TestFunction", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        private static extern string TestFunction();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string dllString = TestFunction();
                Console.WriteLine("String from DLL: " + dllString);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Caught exception: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The C++ code of TestApi.dll:

```
#pragma unmanaged
#include <string>
#include <objbase.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* TestFunction()
{
    // Return string to managed side
    std::string cppString = "This is a string from the unmanaged DLL";
    size_t stringSize = strlen(cppString.c_str()) + sizeof(char);
    char* returnString = (char*)::CoTaskMemAlloc(stringSize);
    strcpy_s(returnString, stringSize, cppString.c_str());
    return returnString;
}
```

The DLL contains 1 entry point as expected (dumpbin /exports TestApi.dll):

```
ordinal hint    RVA         name
1       0       00001010    TestFunction = _TestFunction

Summary
1000    .data
7000    .rdata
1000    .reloc
1000    .rsrc
3000    .text
```

The above .NET application works as expected, printing the following output:

```
String from DLL: This is a string from the unmanaged DLL
```

If I add the following snippet, which adds a TLS callback to the DLL, everything breaks:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/INCLUDE:__tls_used")
#pragma comment(linker, "/INCLUDE:_tls_entry")
#pragma data_seg(".CRT$XLB" )

VOID NTAPI MyCallback(PVOID handle, DWORD reason, PVOID resv)
{
}

extern "C" PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK tls_entry = MyCallback;
```

The DLL now contains 1 entry point as expected, but also a .tls section at the end of "Summary":

```
ordinal hint    RVA         name
1       0       00001010    TestFunction = _TestFunction

Summary
1000    .data
7000    .rdata
1000    .reloc
1000    .rsrc
3000    .text
1000    .tls
```

The .NET application now outputs:

```
Unhandled Exception:
   Unhandled Exception:
Segmentation fault
```

When running the application in Debug I get:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

Dumpbin shows no indication that the DLL should be illformed whatsoever, but nevertheless I get the exceptions above.
When I run my original application the symptoms are the same:

- If a .tls section is available from dumpbin the program crashes with
  access violations
- If no .tls section is available the program works fine

Do I miss something here? Is it possible that DllImport only handles DLLs containing no .tls section?
My obvious solution is to refactor the code so my entry points don't depend on thread logic, so the linker doesn't add the .tls section to the DLL.
But, I would still like to know why this is happening. Any thoughts?

The environment used:

- Windows 7 Enterprise SP1
- Visual Studio 2012
- .NET Framework 4

Comment: Could you give us a simple demo project that doesn't do all that nasty `#pragma` work?

Comment: You are playing with fire of course, there is very little you can do in a TLS callback.  Restrictions are very similar to DllMain().  Your code works fine when I try it, I don't see anything wrong.  Enable unmanaged debugging and set a breakpoint on the callback, perhaps.  You do need to explain where "Segmentation fault" comes from, that's a Unix error message.  And do consider turning off /clr on the C++ project, that makes little sense and in general risks the loader lock problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I couldn't manage to get a working project without the manual TLS callback unfortunately.

Comment: @HansPassant The "Segmentation fault" comes from Cygwin, which was the environment I used when testing the above-mentioned example projects. I tried turning off the /clr flag and it fixed everything! Thanks for your help. This is my first work on loading native DLL from .NET and can't really explain why /clr was enabled in the first place. Do you have any thoughts on why /clr would cause trouble in this case?

Comment: None whatsoever.  Cygwin is however strongly correlated with TLS problems.

Comment: @HansPassant If you post an answer with your hint about turning off /clr, I will mark it as an accepted answer. Otherwise, I will post an answer myself in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the /clr flags does something nasty with the PE format of the DLL. If the /clr flag is enabled I get the following output when loading the DLL from Python 2.7:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> apidll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('TestApi.dll')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Disabling the /clr flag gives me:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> apidll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('TestApi.dll')
>>>
```

My solution (as @HansPassant also suggested in the comment above) was to disable the /clr flag and everything worked even though the DLL contained a .tls section.